# Expanding "Activate Later" functionality

Tags: javascript, dom-events, aem

I would like to call some implemented validation Javascript method

```
validatePageProperties = function() {...}
```

When I click on the Button "Activate Later" (see the pic). Any Idea how to do this?

[image: button in dropdown]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to overlay the siteadmin at /libs/wcm/core/content/siteadmin. Just copy that node structure and place it at /apps/wcm/core/content/siteadmin. Then navigate to /apps/wcm/core/content/siteadmin/actions/activate/menu/activateLater and place your javascript function in the handler property. You may need your custom javascript handler to call the existing handler when it finishes.

Also your custom javascript will need to be loaded in the admin. You can do this by putting it into a client library (cq:ClientLibraryFolder) and assigning it a category of cq.wcm.admin.